# [ROS openni] Cant make openni

Tags: openni, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cant make opennni
distribution:groovy

↓error massage
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/viki/drivers/openni'
cd build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist && bash RedistMaker && cd -

---

- PrimeSense OpenNI Redist    *
- ```
  2013-06-30 21:22:15       *
  ```

---

Target: Linux-x86
Version: 1.5.4.0
Num of compile jobs: 2

- Building OpenNI...
  ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnPlayerImpl.cpp: In constructor ‘xn::PlayerImpl::PlayerImpl()’:
  ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnPlayerImpl.cpp:71:33: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
  ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnRecorderImpl.cpp: In constructor ‘xn::RecorderImpl::RecorderImpl()’:
  ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnRecorderImpl.cpp:51:18: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
  ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/Device.cpp: In function ‘XnStatus openDeviceFromXmlWithChoice(const char*, xn::EnumerationErrors&)’:
  ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/Device.cpp:252:22: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int scanf(const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  /bin/sh: 1: javac: not found
  make[3]: *** [../../../Bin/x86-Release/org.OpenNI.jar] Error 127
  make[2]: *** [Wrappers/OpenNI.java] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  failed to execute: make  -j2 -C /home/viki/drivers/openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/../Build > /home/viki/drivers/openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/Output/BuildOpenNI.txt
  Building Failed!
  make[1]: *** [installed] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/viki/drivers/openni'
  make: *** [openni_lib] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66292/%5Bros-openni%5D-cant-make-openni/) by [Ichiro suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/5224/ichiro-suzuki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are missing javac which is usually in standard JDKs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0